# Python variable is being updated on each loop even though I initialized it outside of the loop

Tags: python, class, while-loop, scope, attributes

Working on a little Fallout minigame in python...

I have a function called level_up that allows player to distribute skill points.

Player's current stats are stored as attributes of the player class.

I created a variable inside the level_up function that copies the player's current stats to compare against while the leveling loop is running. I did this so that the player cannot edit the stat value to be less than what it was when the level up occurred.

I initialized this variable outside of the main loop of the function in order to have it be constant, but as the player makes edits to their stats, this variable (original values) seems to be updated with the new values, instead of staying at what the values were when the level up occurred.

**Example**
(Billy's Small Guns skill is 15 when he levels up. original_values should store that 15 was the original value. Billy adds 5 points to Small Guns, making it 20. He decides he wants to go back to 15. Should work since the original value was 15, but original_values now has Small Guns at 20, so this change can't occur).

I thought initializing original_values outside the loop is what I would need to do. Does this have something to do with the fact that I'm updating class attributes?

Can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong? Thank you.

**The Function**

```
def level_up(self):
        """Formula true to FO1 and FO2"""
        self.lvl += 1

        # flooring the result may not be true to the original game, but am doing for simplicity's sake
        self.hp += math.floor((self.special['end']/2)) + 2
        
        # create skill points to spend
        points = self.skill_rate
        
        # end loop condition
        confirm = False

        # create variables for the original stat values before level up
        original_values = self.combat_skills

        # needs to allow for editing only current changes, cannot go lower than previous values
        while points != 0 and confirm == False:
            print(f'\nSkill Points: {points}')
            for skill, value in self.combat_skills.items():
                print(f'{skill}: {value}')
            
            # get stat to edit
            while True:
                stat_to_edit = input('STAT TO EDIT (ex. small guns) or DONE to confirm: ').lower()
                if stat_to_edit in self.combat_skills.keys():
                    break
                elif stat_to_edit == 'done':
                    if points != 0:
                        print('Must use all skill points before confirming!')
                        continue
                    else:
                        confirm = True
                        break
                else: print('Invalid Entry')
                continue
            
            # get new value


            while True:
                try:
                    new_value = int(input(f'NEW {stat_to_edit.upper()} VALUE: '))
                except ValueError:
                    print('Value must be numerical (ex. 12)')
                    continue
                # make variable for the difference
                change = new_value - self.combat_skills[stat_to_edit]
                # check new value, make sure its not less than original stat value and there are enough points available
                if new_value < original_values[stat_to_edit]:
                    print(f'Cannot reduce stat past original value ({original_values[stat_to_edit]})')
                    continue
                # check points available against the change between current value and new value, not original value
                if change <= points:
                    # change is valid, set new stat value and subtract points from points bank. (negative change values will increase points)
                    self.combat_skills[stat_to_edit] = new_value
                    points -= change
                    break
                else:
                    print(f'Not enough skill points for this change! You need {change}.')
                    continue
```

**The Class**

```
class Player_Character:
    """Represents the player character and all associated stats and possessions. Formulas true to FO1 and FO2"""
    def __init__(self, name, lvl, special):
        self.name = name
        self.lvl = lvl
        self.special = special
        self.hp = 15 + self.special['str'] + (2 * self.special['end'])
        self.ap = 5 + math.floor(self.special['agl']/2)
        self.seq = 2 * self.special['per']
        self.ac = self.special['agl']
        self.carry_weight = 25 + (self.special['str'] * 25)
        self.skill_rate = (self.special['int'] * 2) + 5
        self.weapon = None
        self.armor = None

        # combat skills
        self.small_guns = 35 + self.special['agl']
        self.big_guns = 10 + self.special['agl']
        self.energy_weapons = 10 + self.special['agl']
        # dictionary for use in game and in functions
        self.combat_skills = {'small guns': self.small_guns, 'big guns': self.big_guns, 'energy weapons': self.energy_weapons}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`original_values = self.combat_skills` does not make a copy. It's just another reference to the same object - changes made via one reference will be seen no matter which reference you use to access them because they're all the same object.

If you want to make a distinct copy use the `copy` method of the `dict` to make a copy. e.g. `original_values = self.combat_skills.copy()`